# Node JS - Big Query insert to a request object fully into a record data type

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I have Json  which I am getting from client side. The entire request I need to insert into a big query table.

How can I write an insert query without specifying single fields

The below is the req object

```
var reqBody = {
   "Name":"testing",
   "columns":[
      {
         "fieldExistsIn":"BOTH",
         "columnWidth":5,
         "hide":false
      },
      {
         "fieldExistsIn":"BOTH",
         "columnWidth":10,
         "hide":false
      }
   ],
   "Range":{
      "startDate":"20-Oct-2022",
      "endDate":"26-Oct-2022"
   }
}
```

I need to insert it into a field 'requestData' like below. But the below query is not working

```
"INSERT INTO table_name(requestData) VALUES(reqBody)"
```

1.BigQuery Table Schema

```
reqData RECORD  NULLABLE    
  Name  STRING  NULLABLE    
  column    RECORD  REPEATED
      fieldExistsIn STRING  NULLABLE
      columnWidth   INTEGER NULLABLE    
      hide  BOOLEAN NULLABLE
```

2.Sample Output table

```
"requestData": {
      "Name": "testing",
      "columns": [
        {
          "fieldExistsIn":"BOTH",
          "columnWidth": 10,
          "hide": false
        },
        {
          "fieldExistsIn":"BOTH",
          "columnWidth": 5,
          "hide": false
        }]
    }
```

3.How are you trying to insert the JSON file

```
using nodejs application
```

Comment: Could you provide the following details as it will be helpful to replicate 
1.BigQuery Table Schema 
2.Sample Output table
3.How are you trying to insert the JSON file i.e through Console or CLI or BigQuery Client Libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the table schema and sample data you have provided, I tried to replicate it on my end .

**Table schema :**

[image]

Using the INSERT query to insert the json data throws an error.

```
insert into project.try.tab5 (reqData) values(var1)
```

Where in var1 I have stored the json data.

**Error :** Inserted row has wrong column count; Has 1, expected 2

So, if you want to use Node.js client, you can use the [insertRowsAsStream](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/b95a743e9b1e550b14ebb052ba575210137809ac/samples/insertRowsAsStream.js) method to insert rows to the table.

You can refer to the below code and the corresponding output.

**Sample.js :**

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigquery = new BigQuery();
async function insertRowsAsStream() {
   const datasetId = 'sandeep';
   const tableId = 'tab8';
  const rows = [

    {
        "reqData": {
          "Name": [
            "testing"
          ],
          "column": [
            {
              "fieldExistsIn": "BOTH",
              "columnWidth": "10",
              "hide": false
            },
            {
              "fieldExistsIn": "BOTH",
              "columnWidth": "5",
              "hide": false
            }
          ]
        }
      }

  ];
    
  await bigquery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .insert(rows);
  console.log(`Inserted ${rows.length} rows`);
}
insertRowsAsStream();
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: PartialFailureError is gettingI a using a key to connect the db. Is that could be the reason

Comment: Hi @user1187, For me initially PartialFailureError occured because the json data that was inserted into BigQuery table through Node.js Client Library was not aligned with the table schema in BigQuery. Could you try to check your BigQuery table schema with the json data that you are passing are aligned or not.

Comment: How can i do an update in similar way