# Node JS - Big Query update table with a request object

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

Based on below request object I need to update the table

```
var reqBody = {
   "Name":"testing11",
   "columns":[
      {
         "fieldExistsIn":"BOTH",
         "columnWidth":5,
         "hide":false
      },
      {
         "fieldExistsIn":"BOTH",
         "columnWidth":10,
         "hide":false
      }
   ],
   "Range":{
      "startDate":"20-Oct-2022",
      "endDate":"26-Oct-2022"
   }
}


UPDATE table_name
SET requestData = reqBody
WHERE requestData.Name = reqBody.oldName;
```

I am doing the insertion using the below query

```
await bigquery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .insert(reqBody);
```

For table schema you can refer the below question

[Node JS - Big Query insert to a request object fully into a record data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69987111/node-js-big-query-insert-to-a-request-object-fully-into-a-record-data-type)

Comment: Which column do you want to perform the update on ? What is the where condition ?

Comment: In the linked question you have the “Name” column as "Repeated" type that means it's an array. Do you really need it to be an array as in the where condition you want to check equality of names? Otherwise, there will be multiple names in each row.

Comment: Oh no name is not a repeated field

Comment: Hi @user1187, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As per the table schema and sample data you have provided, I tried to replicate it on my end.

**Table schema:**

[image]

As per your requirement, I have modified the code by referring to the [queryParamsStructs](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/main/samples/queryParamsStructs.js) and [query](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/main/samples/query.js) sample codes from Google BigQuery Node.js Client API. To update multiple columns in a table using a JSON object through the BigQuery Client API, we have to write an **UPDATE** query and pass it in the code. The JSON object should be passed in **params** and you should have to access that JSON object in the **UPDATE** query as like below:

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigquery = new BigQuery();
async function query() {
   // Queries the U.S. given names dataset for the state of Texas.

   const query = `UPDATE
     \`ProjectID.DatasetID.TableID\`
       SET reqData.columns = ARRAY(
       SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM UNNEST(@reqData.columns)
       ),
       reqData.Range.startDate = CAST(@reqData.Range.startDate AS DATE),
       reqData.Range.endDate = CAST(@reqData.Range.endDate AS DATE)
       WHERE reqData.Name = @reqData.Name`;
   // For all options, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query
   const options = {
     query: query,
     // Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
     location: 'US',
     params: {
           "reqData": {
             "Name": "testing",
             "columns": [
               {
                 "fieldExistsIn": "One",
                 "columnWidth": 1,
                 "hide": true
               },
               {
                 "fieldExistsIn": "four",
                 "columnWidth": 4,
                 "hide": true
               }
             ],
             "Range":{
               "startDate": "2021-1-11",
               "endDate": "2022-2-22"
            }
           }
       },
   };
   // Run the query as a job
   const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
   console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);

   // Wait for the query to finish
   const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();

   // Print the results
   console.log('Rows:');
   rows.forEach(row => console.log(row));
 }
 // [END bigquery_query]
 query();
```

**Initial Data:**

[image]

**Updated Result:**

[image]

**Note**: If you have inserted the rows to the table recently by using streaming insert,  the rows cannot be modified with UPDATE, DELETE or MERGE within the last 30 minutes. Refer to this [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language#limitations) doc for more information.  If you tried to update a table within the last 30 mins, you will get the below error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: UPDATE or DELETE statement over table projectID.datasetID.tableID would affect rows in the streaming buffer, which is not supported
```

Comment: I'm excited to announce that mutating DML statements (UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE) over recently streamed data via the BigQuery Storage Write API* is now supported in public preview!! Check it out the feature and how to allowlist your project here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api#use_data_manipulation_language_dml_with_recently_streamed_data.

*This feature only supports recently streamed data via the BigQuery Storage Write API, not the legacy insertAll streaming API.